# Regarding Postman

Tags: post

For Normal Postman Input i gave as Body like this for group of Accounts in postman uri
https://domain name/services/data/v36.0/composite/tree/account/

using post method

```
{
"records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount1",
    "phone" : "1111111111",
    "website" : "www.salesforce1.com",
    "industry" : "Banking"   
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount2",
    "phone" : "2222222222",
    "website" : "www.salesforce2.com",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref3"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount3",
    "phone" : "3333333333",
    "website" : "www.salesforce3.com",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref4"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount4",
    "phone" : "4444444444",
    "website" : "www.salesforce4.com",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    }]
}
```

It is Inserting

While I am Using Curl Command Prompt
for post body like this in command

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: OAuth 00D280000013mzk!AQUAQKnGCLaJo2F0fmpegSMy4VSBCXVPJygVZG8Zf2rj7E6NJE3yueMITIxIAJT0YVjxpoJRe4PRR6okbPH6A86DAVMGVAEH" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 7db97417-e223-1319-a64e-4a72236b89dd" -d '{\
"records" :[{
    \"attributes\" : {\"type\" : \"Account\", \"referenceId\" : \"ref1\"},
    \"name\" : \"SampleAccount1\",
    \"phone\" : \"1111111111\",
    \"website\" : \"www.salesforce1.com\",
    \"industry\" : \"Banking\"
    },{
   \"attributes\" : {\"type\" : \"Account\", \"referenceId\" : \"ref2\"},
    \"name\" : \"SampleAccount2\",
    \"phone\" : \"1111111111\",
    \"website\" : \"www.salesforce1.com\",
    \"industry\" : \"Banking\" 
    }]\
}\' "https://domain name/services/data/v36.0/composite/tree/account/"

It is Showing Error like

**for every line executing in command prompt , it is Showing Error like
is not Recognised as an Internal or External Command,Operable Program or Batch File How to Rectify the Error , How to Give curl Input, Please anayone Rectify the Error**

Comment: end of line symbols are making new command in terminal. so, join your request in one line and execute

Comment: Please Share the Answer

Comment: for How to give input for above Request in Curl

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vUs6VQiq

Comment: Share the Answer

Comment: just send you your example in paste bin